# How to check dataframe rows as string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops

I have a df containing twitter data, that has been cleaned. I was running an analysis on the locations from where the tweets are from. Specifically I wanted to check if a tweet is from USA or not. The data frame contains locations like "New York, USA". I wanted my code to check every row and see if it contains "USA". Here is the code I used:

```
count=0
for x in df['location']:
    if 'USA' in x:
            count=count+1
print ('From USA:', count)
```

but the following traceback occurred:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: does you data contain NaNs?

Comment: Better to use `for x in df` and check `if 'USA' in x['location']`, this might help.

Comment: use `for x in df['location'].astype(str):` instead.

Comment: Please provide sample dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Better, you can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) here

```py
count = df.location.str.contains('USA').sum()
print ('From USA:', count)
```